# FIFA 15:UT Windows 10 black screen

Tags: windows, fifa-15

I have downloaded FIFA 15:UT to my laptop from the Windows store. My laptop is currently running on Windows 10 64 bit. My laptop configuration is:

> Processor: core i5
>   RAM:4 GB
>   Graphics: Intel(R) HD graphics
>   Approx total graphics memory: 1696 GB

When I try to run this game it only shows a black screen.

What is the reason behind it? How can I solve it?

Note: The other app I have downloaded from Windows store works fine.

Comment: I guess it's not yet optimized or your videocard driver is out of date. Or there isn't a official win10 driver for now.

Comment: Has this game ever worked for you on Windows 10?

Comment: Requesting confirmation on the graphics card. Even dedicated cards do not offer 1696GB of available memory.. that said, I have seen a few driver issues with the Windows 10 update. Graphics seems the most effected, but its a driver issue. Inevitably the company will release a driver update, and fix the problems. One of the problems associated with a new OS release.